# how to use 2dicts in a for loop in Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have context as below :

```
    context = {
    'author': author,
    'books':books,
}
```

Now I need to use author and books in One for loop like this :

```
{% for each in ***author & books***  %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ each.author.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ each.book.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ each.book.pubishDate }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How to make such a for loop in Django template?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

join 2 dictionaries into a list before sending it to the template(i.e in the view):

```
dicts = [dict1, dict2]
```

and try this:

```
{% for d in dicts %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ d.x }} </td>
        <td> {{ d.y }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```